# How do I control what a HTML page returns on a GET request

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple web API that outputs the base64 encoded image string of a Desmos graph of the provided equation. (I included the code below) It works fine except for the fact that when a GET request is sent to the website, it returns the code of the website that was used to create the image, with the base64 image nowhere to be found.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="calculator" style="width: 100%; height: 100vh;"></div>
        <script src="https://www.desmos.com/api/v1.5/calculator.js?apiKey=dcb31709b452b1cf9dc26972add0fda6"></script>
        <script>
          const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          console.log(urlParams)
    
          const formula = urlParams.get('formula')
          const step = urlParams.get('step')
          const image = urlParams.get('image')
          const api = urlParams.get('api')
    
          console.log(formula)
          console.log(step)
          console.log(image)
    
          var options
    
          var imageMode = ({
            expressions: false,
            settingsMenu: false,
            border: false,
            zoomButtons: false,
          });
    
          if(image === "true") {
            options = imageMode
          }
    
          var elt = document.getElementById('calculator');
          var calculator = Desmos.GraphingCalculator(elt,options);
          calculator.setExpression({ id: 'graph1', latex: formula });
          console.log(calculator.screenshot())
    
          if(api === "true") {
            results = (`<pre>${calculator.screenshot()}</pre>`)
            document.body.innerHTML = results
          }
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When everything is said and done, I want this page to return the plain base64 encoded image string (ideally) or HTML that actually has the string in it could work as well. I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Is this a website that serves static content? If so, doing a `GET` for your HTML file _should_ send the HTML back in the response. How are you doing this `GET`? By putting a URL into your browser, or are you doing something else to fetch this HTML?

Comment: Note: Don't leave your api keys visible mate. Although in this occasion it's not that harmful, you should remove them and replace them with a something like (my_key) or <my api key>

Comment: calculator.screenshot() is the base64 image, you need to put it in a img tag for it to render the actual image, not console log it.

Comment: @Jacob Specifically, I am trying to make a API for requesting images of a graph for a given equation using the Desmos API. (Its for another Node.JS project I am working on) I am doing this since the Desmos API doesn't support Node.js and "direct image generation".

What I essentially want to do is for the page to return the value for the "results" (which is the base64 image string) variable in the GET response.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thank you for your response. What I want to do is not generate a image. I want to keep it as a base64 image. When I use a API tester, like ReqBin for example, it returns the HTML code of the page. I want it to return the base64 image string.

Comment: @ΚωνσταντινοςΧαφης Thank you for your response and thank you for the concern. It is a "development" API key that is readily available on the public Desmos API documentation, so I didn't think it was important to hide it.

Comment: @Jacob, Desmos has an example on their website of how to handle the output of caculator.screenshot() that I think will help you out ... https://www.desmos.com/api/v1.5/docs/index.html#GraphingCalculator.screenshot

Answer (score 0):

This API only seems to only operate within the context of an HTML DOM (such as a browser). To work around this and generate images with NodeJS code, you'd need to have a server-side DOM. [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer) is one option. It allows you to run a headless Chromium browser which you can manipulate via a NodeJS API. So at a high level, your API code could:

1. Start a puppeteer browser
2. Open a puppeteer page to the HTML for generating the graph
3. Call the puppeteer API to generate a screenshot
4. Send the screenshot image in the API response

Other headless browsers like PhantomJS also exist as well, so you'll want to look around at what options are available to you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes. The API only works in a DOM, and I thought that my solution (through a GET on my website) would work. Puppeteer is unviable for my use case for multiple reasons. Is there any way to make "my way" work? (As in getting the base64 string from my website somehow?)

Comment: @JVKX no as xhr or curl etc won't render the page before returning it

Comment: I'm not aware of any technologies that run inline HTML scripts on a server, manipulate the DOM server-side, then serve up the modified HTML short of running in a headless browser. You haven't clarified why puppeteer won't work for you; maybe try PhantomJS?